# Connect to Azure Virtual machine from Mobile App locally

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-virtual-machine

I'm using Azure Mobile App and classic Virtual Machine on Azure Portal.

There is a great tool on Mobile App - API. I use it for different tasks. 
My question is -can I somehow connect to server from mobile app API using local interface?

For instance, I want to deploy web server on virtual machine and restrict connections only from local subnet? And I will use mobile app API to communicate with it. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect Azure mobile App with Azure Virtual Machine, we have two solution. 1) [VNET Intergration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) 2) [Hybrid Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/biztalk-services/integration-hybrid-connection-overview). Of course, we can deploy mobile project to Azure Virtual Machine directly. If you want the server only be accessed by the web server, please consider the design in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/network-overview). Put the server in the backend and put the web server in the frontend. Use NSG to limit the sever so that it only be accessed by the web server.